# Why in HaMapil do we ask to wake up in peace twice?

Tags: tefilla, hamapil

In the bedtime Shema, Nusach Ashkenaz includes this phrase in HaMapil:

> שתשכיביני לשלום ותעמידיני לשלום
>
> [May it be Your will...] that You lay me down in peace and that You stand me up in peace

Nusach Sefard, Eidus HaMizrach, and Ari all read:

> ותעמידיני לחיים טובים ולשלום
>
> ...and that You stand me up to a good and peaceful life

All Nusachos include the following phrase later in the Beracha:

> והאר עיני פן אישן המות
>
> Enlighten my eyes, lest I sleep [the sleep] of death.

These seemingly mean the same thing; why must we say it twice?

This question is further compounded by the fact that while the Gemara (Berachos 60b) has a very different text of HaMapil from what we have, it does include והאר עיני פן אישן המות but does not include ותעמידיני לשלום.

Comment: I don't see the "peace" part as repetitive. Unless you want to be particular grammatically by including "Shalom" at the end, only. Otherwise, it's requesting that bot resting as well as awakening should both be peaceful. Perhaps, the rest request is that you shouldn't suffer from nightmares, or someone shouldn't rob or attack you while you sleep. Likewise, since sleep is considered a fraction of death, you hope to actually awaken in the morning peacefully vs. not at all or awakening with a severe illness or injury.

Comment: @DanF My issue isn’t re תשכיביני לשלום vs. תעמידיני לשלום. It’s תעמידיני לשלום vs. והאר עיני וכו׳.

Comment: What’s the problem? One’s ‘please let me wake up’, and the other’s ‘please let me wake up peacefully’

Comment: @Loani See my reply to DanF above

Comment: What’s the problem? One’s ‘please let me wake up’, and the other’s ‘please let me wake up peacefully

Comment: ‘You stand me up in peace’-[let] you wake me up without problems (I.e. pain etc), ‘Enlighten my eyes, lest I sleep [the sleep] of death‘- let me wake up (I.e. not die in my sleep!)

Comment: @Loani All the more reason to only ask for the former! Asking to wake up without pain already implies a request to wake up to begin with!

Comment: It should be backwards, that doesn’t mean that one is worthless